# Web.config - Keyword not supported: 'workstation id'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, ef-database-first, sqlclient

I uploaded on a ftp server of somee.com a website written in ASP.NET MVC.

In web.config, I've a problem with this part :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Entities" connectionString="workstation id=ICookDB.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=***;pwd=***;data source=ICookDB.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=ICookDB" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

For Some pages, I've this error :

```
[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'workstation id'.]
System.Data.EntityClient.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms) +8420372
System.Data.EntityClient.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms) +82
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +102
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +43
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +78
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +32
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +127
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +13
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +346
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +52
```

Comment: What type of database are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework, Linq2Sql, or DAO?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Entity Framework with and .edmx model because of the use of EntityClient

EntityClient uses it's own format embedding the actual SqlClient connection string inside.

The format looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksEntities"
        connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
                          provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                          provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;multipleactiveresultsets=true'"
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So in your case you may try something like this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities"
        connectionString="metadata=<Path-to-your-CSDL>.csdl|<Path-to-your-SSDL>.ssdl|<Path-to-your-MSL>.msl;
                          provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                          provider connection string='workstation id=ICookDB.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=***;pwd=***;data source=ICookDB.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=ICookDB'"
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Make sure you replace `<Path-to-your-SSDL>`, `<Path-to-your-MSL>` and `<Path-to-your-CSDL>` to the correct locations.

You can get more information on how to create a correct connection string here:
[EntityConnection.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Comment: As an FYI, the code linked to create the connection string at the bottom of your link only works if the executing assembly is also storing the SSDL/MSL/CSDL files.  If the edmx is stored in another assembly the code won't work and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24946835/209259) provides a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Database first, you must pass an *Entity Connection String*.  The following will build an Entity Connection String from a standard SQL Connection string:

```
public static string BuildEntityConnectionString(string connectionString, 
  Type contextType)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    string prefix = contextType.Namespace
      .Replace(contextType.Assembly.GetName().Name, 
      "");

    if (prefix.Length > 0
        && prefix.StartsWith("."))
    {
        prefix = prefix.Substring(1, prefix.Length - 1);
    }

    if (prefix.Length > 1
        && !prefix.EndsWith("."))
    {
        prefix += ".";
    }

    EntityConnectionStringBuilder csBuilder = 
      new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

    csBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    csBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = connectionString;
    csBuilder.Metadata = string.Format("res://{0}/{1}.csdl|"
                                        + "res://{0}/{1}.ssdl|"
                                        + "res://{0}/{1}.msl"
                                        , ContextType.Assembly.FullName
                                        , prefix + ContextType.Name);

    result =  csBuilder.ToString();

    return result;
}
```

Then when you create your context:

```
var connectionString = // however you get your connection string;
if (connectionString.IndexOf("metadata", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
  == -1)
{
  connectionString = BuildEntityConnectionString(connectionString
    typeof(MyDbContext));
}

var myContext = new MyDbContext(connectionString);
```